# Using Filter Condition While Joining Spark Dataframes: Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

can someone please suggest me how to use filter while joining 2 dataframes in spark scala.I am trying below code.

```
    var name="abcd"
    var last_name="xyz"

    val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
    .filter(df1("name")==='${name}').
    filter(df1("last_name")==='${last_name}')
    .drop(df1("name"))
    .drop(df2("name"))
```

But getting multiple error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is not like java's JDBC APIs where we need wrap string with single quotes for where condition.
Can you simple try using `name` variable w/o any quotes and $ sign

```
    var name="abcd"
    var last_name="xyz"
    val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"))
    .filter(df1("name")===name && df1("last_name")===last_name)
    .drop(df1("name"))
    .drop(df2("name"))
```

Comment: Yes it worked  for adding multiple filter condition do i need to use multiple filter or i can use &&?

Comment: please use `&&` for multiple filters